# How To Assign a Type to an Empty Object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, object, types

I'm trying to create a counter that says which character appears the most in a string.

```
function maxChar(str: string) {
  const strObj = {}
  let maxCount = 0
  let maxChar = ""

  for (let char of str) {
    strObj[char] = strObj[char] + 1 || 1 
  }
  for (let key in strObj) {
    if (strObj[key] > maxCount) {
      maxCount = strObj[key]
      maxChar = key
    }
  }
  return maxChar 
}
```

However, Typescript underscores *strObj[char]* and *strObj[key]*, giving error:

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'*

Apparently *strObj = {}* needs a type assigned, but I have no idea how to assign a type to an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `strObj` like a dictionary whose keys are any character and whose values are `number` (or `undefined`).  The closest thing built into TypeScript is a type with a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
const strObj: { [k: string]: number } = {}
```

Now the compiler will let you index into `strObj` with any `string`-valued key (including all the single-character-long strings), and it will allow you to read/write a `number` value from it.  (Technically maybe it should be more careful with `undefined`, but most people do the right thing with `undefined` and index signatures, so the compiler ignores it.  If you really care you can write `number | undefined` or enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), but all that will do is make it more annoying to write your code.)

Anyway, now the rest of your code example will compile with no error.

Note that the type `{[k: string]: number}` can also be written as `Record<string, number>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  Either way corresponds to an object type which allows any `string` as a key and whose value, if present, will be of type `number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYA8DCALVAnACgGco8AuREvGMAcwEpEBvAWAChFPEIETLSA8gCMAVhSaIA2gGsKVGrQC6FMCGRCApnkQBfRAF5mO9l0QAbDVBQZMccFcMAGE1wtW0WXNsMAiH+xdOYDhtAjduL0Q4YH48RlYOUy4qYRFJCC9FA1jU9MzEAGpEAEZEAB8yksDdauDQ8OkNAE9EGhzReOrTGBjiQVEZZqyAPmssOzAoTsSkpI9be2yUgcamxS7ZsZx8bNWNzmMZmqO8SxA8JHmvdkP2IA)